# values should be display based on drop down list

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

if i select a drop down values form database,after that the title values should be display,example i select about us page from drop down,after that title values should be display help me any one

view page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="POST">
    <?php foreach ($seo_tag_update as $rows) { ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select Pages:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="select_update_page" id="select_update_page">
                    <option value=""> -- select pages -- </option>
                    <?php
                    echo '<option value="' . $rows->page_id . '">' . $rows->page_name . '</option>';
                    ?>  
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Title:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">   
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="update_title" id="update_title " value="<?php echo $rows->page_title; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><?php } ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn btn-sumit">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
public function update() {
$this->load->helper('url');
$data['seo_tag_update'] = $this->Question_Insertion_Model->seo_tag_Update();
echo "$posted_id";
$this->load->view('update', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function seo_tag_Update() {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('kas_all_pages s');
$this->db->join('kas_all_pages_tags q','s.page_id=q.page_fk');
$this->db->where('s.page_id', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $result = $query->result();
}
```

Comment: What is actually occurring? What is the problem you're having? Are there any errors?

Comment: no error ..in drop down i select the value like about us,after select the about us title values should be display.but present in my code before select the drop down field title values disapling

Comment: I'm still very confused what the goal is. You're creating a new `<select>` element and title `<input>` each time you loop, but only one submission button.

Comment: before selecting only drop down fields,input values(update title) values displaying..but my requirment is after select the drop down input field values should be display @kchason

Comment: Should there be more than one? Or a total of one `<select>` element (drop down) and one `<input type="text" />` (title)?

Comment: multiple values in drop down

Comment: Just a tip: So you dont have to write extra code I see here you have `return $result = $query->result();` All you need to do is `return $query->result();` Just a little less code.

Comment: sir my requirment is if select the drop down values after that only input text title value should be display...before selecting drop down only text title values are displaying

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're looping and creating multiple `<select>` (and `<input>`) elements, rather than creating the elements and only generating the `<option>` elements.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="POST">
    <!-- CREATE SELECT ELEMENT -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select Pages:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control" name="select_update_page" id="select_update_page">
                <option value=""> -- select pages -- </option>
       <!-- ADD OPTIONS TO DROPDOWN -->
       <?php 
       foreach ($seo_tag_update as $rows) { 
                    echo '<option value="' . $rows->page_id . '">' . $rows->page_name . '</option>';

       } 
       ?>  
       <!-- CLOSE SELECT ELEMENT -->      
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>
       <!-- CREATE TITLE ELEMENT --> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Title:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">   
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="update_title" id="update_title " value="">
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn btn-sumit">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Then you'll need some JavaScript to update the value on change. There are ways to do this in "vanilla" JavaScript, or if you're already including jQuery, you can look at the `.change()` function ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/change/)).